# PrintServiceLookup returns NULL

Tags: service, printing, null, default

I am using PrintServiceLookup to search for default print services installed on a client machine using an applet. This code works fine on my machine and the applet loads properly and returns default print service name but when my machine is access from another client the applet returns BLANK on one machine and NullPointerException on another because PrintSerivceLookup returns NULL on that machine.

Furthermore, when on those machine I try running the applet using Main method call, it works perfectly.

Please suggest.

The code which I wrote:

```
HTML:
APPLET code="CheckClientDefaultPrinterAddress.class" width=350 height=125 name="printerApp"

SCRIPT:
var defaultPrinterIp = document.printerApp.getDefaultPrinterIP();
alert(defaultPrinterIp);

JAVA CODE:
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
if(service != null) {
    defaultPrinter = service.getName();
}
```

return defaultPrinter;

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the following line in Java.policy file:

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

but stil not able to find out the exact permission which is required. Giving All permissions is not safe for applets.